# How to concatenate streams in rxjs?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am trying to get data from the server using rxjs:

```
class HolidaysService {
    constructor() {
        this.restService = newRestService();
    }

    public getHolidaysByYear(year: number): Observable<Date[]> {
        const endpoint = `/get${year}`;
        return this.restService.GET(endpoint, { cache: true })
            .pipe(map(dates: any)=> dates.map((item: string) => new Date(item)))
    }

    public getHolidaysByYears(years: number[]): Observable<Date[]> {
        const requests = years.reduce((acc,v)=>acc.concat(this.getHolidaysByYear(v)),[])
        return forkJoin(...requests).pipe(scan((acc,v)=>acc.concat(v), []))
    }

}

// We call it:
const holidayService = new HolidaysService();
const substriction1 = holidayService.getHolidaysByYear(2020)
    .subscribe(
        res => console.log('res', res),
        err => console.warn(err)
    );
substriction1.unsunscribe();
```

The console displays res and the data itself. Now I want to get information for several years using rxjs-analogue of promise.all:

```
const substriction2 = holidayService.getHolidaysByYears([2019,2020])
    .subscribe(
        res => console.log('res', res),
        err => console.warn(err)
    );
substriction2.unsunscribe();
```

And nothing works. I do not see res in the console and data. What could be the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would write `Promise.all` analogue in the RxJS with `forkJoin`:

```
public getHolidaysByYears(years: number[]): Observable<Date[]> {
    const requests = years.map(year => this.getHolidaysByYear(year));
    return forkJoin(requests).pipe(concatAll());
}
```

Note that I am using `concatAll` operator, because `forkJoin(requests)` will give you `Observable<Date[][]>`, that is Array of holiday dates per year. Since your return type is `Observable<Date[]>`, that's why I am using `concatAll` operator to concatenate the resulting Arrays and get the `Observable<Date[]>` instead of `Observable<Date[][]>`.